# Android Listview Custom Section Header

Tags: android, listview, customization

How can i implement custom section or header of ListView like Instagram app in android.

http://prsarahevans.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/06/photo.PNG

When scroll up the bar that have userpic, name and time still be there and when other header bar go near it then animate like push it up.

Thank you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I was able to solve this issue by using scroll listener on the listview. (tested on 2.1)

Lets say for each list row I have a layout like the one below. There is a content part and a header part. It doesn't matter what view type you use for header or content.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:background="#FFFFFF">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop" 
        android:src="@drawable/pic"
        android:background="#aaaaff" 
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/header"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:padding="12dp"
        android:text="Deneme Row"
        android:textColor="#000000" 
        android:background="#99ffffff"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

The test layout for the activity is as in the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
    </ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Finally the code for the activity is given below. Here I had to have an adapter which uses ViewHolder to store the header view and also a variable to keep track of the change in the scroll for each successive scroll events (previousTop). This is because of the fact that offsetTopAndBottom() changes offset of the view related to the previous location of it.

```
public class TestActivity extends Activity implements AbsListView.OnScrollListener{

    ListView list; 
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
        list.setAdapter(new Adapter(this));        
        list.setOnScrollListener(this); 
    }

    @Override
    public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem,
            int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {     
        //the listview has only few children (of course according to the height of each child) who are visible
        for(int i=0; i < list.getChildCount(); i++){
            View child = list.getChildAt(i);
            ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) child.getTag();

            //if the view is the first item at the top we will do some processing
            if(i == 0){             
                boolean isAtBottom = child.getHeight() <= holder.header.getBottom();
                int offset = holder.previousTop - child.getTop();
                if(!(isAtBottom && offset > 0)){                    
                    holder.previousTop = child.getTop();
                    holder.header.offsetTopAndBottom(offset);                   
                    holder.header.invalidate();
                }
            } //if the view is not the first item it "may" need some correction because of view re-use
            else if (holder.header.getTop() != 0) {
                int offset = -1 * holder.header.getTop(); 
                holder.header.offsetTopAndBottom(offset);
                holder.previousTop = 0;
                holder.header.invalidate();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {}

    private static class Adapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
        public Adapter(Context context) {
            super(context, R.layout.row, R.id.header);
            for(int i=0; i < 50; i++){
                add(Integer.toString(i));
            }
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            if(convertView == null){
                convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.row, parent, false);
                ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder();
                holder.header = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.header);
                convertView.setTag(holder);             
            }
            ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            holder.header.setText(getItem(position));
            return convertView;
        }
    }

    private static class ViewHolder {
        TextView header;
        int previousTop = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey siyamed ,
This is very useful .
In my case I've one more ListView(child) inside ListView(Parent) . so header is not working properly when i'm scrolling-Down ....

Comment: If there is no data in child-listview , then it works properly ..
> sample app
https://bitbucket.org/ashish2py/instagramheader

Comment: Thanks for your answer.. but i have one question that i am using 10 type of custom_row in one listview so, how can i manage this custom header in that.. if you have any idea regarding my question then please answer me..Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I've improved Siyamed's question a little bit so that the header is not gone when the view is redrawn for example if a bitmap in the listview item is changed.

Instead of using coordinates relative to the last position I use coordinates relative to the top of the view and use padding instead of offsets.

```
@Override
public void onScroll(AbsListView absListView, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {

    for(int i=0; i < list.getChildCount(); i++){
        View child = list.getChildAt(i);
        ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) child.getTag();

        if(i == 0){
            try {
                boolean isAtBottom = child.getHeight() <= holder.movingHeader.getBottom();
                if(!(isAtBottom)){
                    if (child.getTop() >= 0){}
                    else if (child.getHeight() - movingHeader.getHeight() - 1 > -child.getTop())
                    {
                        holder.movingHeader.setPadding(0, -child.getTop(), 0, 0);
                        holder.movingHeader.invalidate();
                    }
                    else {
                        holder.movingHeader.setPadding(0, child.getHeight() - movingHeader.getHeight(), 0, 0);
                        holder.movingHeader.invalidate();
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        else if (holder.movingHeader.getPaddingTop() != 0)
        {
            holder.movingHeader.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
            holder.movingHeader.invalidate();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using list view then have 2 views inside your list item.  One is header and other is actually item.

Hide header view initially and as scroll state changes or user touches your list item change the visibility of header.

Answer (score 0):

After your setcontentview do something like the below code.

```
    ListView list = getListView();
    View footer = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.footerlayout, list, false);
    View header = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.headerlayout, list, false);
    list.addHeaderView(header);
    list.addFooterView(footer);
```

Answer (score -1):

I know this question is a little old, but managed to find the StickyListHeaders library, which does a pretty good job of abstracting the creation of the section headers.

https://github.com/emilsjolander/StickyListHeaders