# Android List View with pinned section headers having two text views in row and one in header

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, android-custom-view

I want to make a custom ListView with section headers and a row layout having two text views.
I have worked around a lot of tutorials and SO questions, and from that work I was able to make a custom ListView with section headers, but they are not pinned.
I followed [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9472507/android-listview-custom-section-header); in this case, when I followed exactly what is described in the SO answer, so that the layout of the row is having a TextView with sublist, then headers are pinned but when I used my own layout then it's working but headers are no more pinned.
I want to make these headers pinned. Code is given below; thanks in advance for your help.

**Note:** I am aware of open-source libraries such as amazing-list-view, PinnedHeadersSections, etc.
I want a custom one; any sort of help in this regard will be appreciated.

**header.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/header"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
</LinearLayout>
```

**header.xml (alternative header.xml with sublist view as in SO answer which inflates pinned headers)**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/header"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="150dp" >
    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

**row_layout.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="5" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/day"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:background="#000"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/description"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:background="#000"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="4" />
</LinearLayout>
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

      <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
      </ListView>

   </LinearLayout>
```

**HeadersListActivity.java**

```
 public class HeadersListActivity extends ListActivity implements OnClickListener{

    ListView listView ;

    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    static class SimpleAdapter extends ArrayAdapter implements OnScrollListener,HeadersListAdapter{

        private LayoutInflater inflator;
        private List list;
        private ListView listView;

        @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        private Activity activity;

        private static class ViewHolder {
            private TextView header;
            private TextView day;
            private TextView description;
            int previousTop = 0;
            public ViewHolder(){}
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        public SimpleAdapter(Activity activity,ArrayList<Item> list, ListView listView){
            super(activity.getApplicationContext(),0,list);
            this.activity = activity;
            this.list = list;
            this.listView = listView;
            this.listView.setOnScrollListener(this);
            inflator = LayoutInflater.from(activity.getApplicationContext());
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, android.view.ViewGroup parent) {
                ViewHolder holder = null ;              
                View itemView = convertView;
                Item item = (Item) list.get(position);
                if(item.type == Item.SECTION){
                    holder = new ViewHolder();
                    itemView = inflator.inflate(R.layout.header, null);
                    holder.header = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
                    holder.header.setTextColor(Color.DKGRAY);
                    holder.header.setText(item.text);
                    itemView.setTag(holder);
                    itemView.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);

                } else {
                    if(itemView == null){
                        itemView = inflator.inflate(R.layout.row_layout, null); 
                        holder = new ViewHolder();
                        holder.day = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.day);
                        holder.description = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.description);

                        itemView.setTag(holder);
                    } else holder = (ViewHolder)itemView.getTag();

                    if(item.type == Item.ITEM){                     

                        holder.day.setTextColor(Color.DKGRAY);
                        holder.day.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
                        holder.day.setText(item.toString());

                        holder.description.setTextColor(Color.DKGRAY);
                        holder.description.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
                        holder.description.setText(item.getDescription());
                    }
                }
                return itemView;
        }

        @Override
        public int getViewTypeCount() {
            return 2;
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemViewType(int position) {
            return ((Item) list.get(position)).type;
        }

        @Override
        public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {

            for(int i=0; i < listView.getChildCount(); i++){
                View child = listView.getChildAt(i);
                ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) child.getTag();
                Item item = (Item) list.get(i);

                if(item.type == Item.SECTION && (holder.header != null)){
                    //if the view is the first item at the top we will do some processing
                    if(i == 0){             
                        boolean isAtBottom = child.getHeight() <= holder.header.getBottom();
                        int offset = holder.previousTop - child.getTop();
                        if(!(isAtBottom && offset > 0)){                    
                            holder.previousTop = child.getTop();
                            holder.header.offsetTopAndBottom(offset);                   
                            holder.header.invalidate();
                        }
                    } //if the view is not the first item it "may" need some correction because of view re-use
                    else if (holder.header.getTop() != 0) {
                        int offset = -1 * holder.header.getTop(); 
                        holder.header.offsetTopAndBottom(offset);
                        holder.previousTop = 0;
                        holder.header.invalidate();
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView arg0, int arg1) {          
        }
    }

    static class Item {
        public static final int SECTION = 0;
        public static final int ITEM = 1;

        private final int type;
        private String text ;
        private String description ;

        public int sectionPosition;
        public int listPosition;

        public Item(int type,String text){
            this.type = type;
            this.text = text;
        }

        public Item(int type,String text,String description){
            this.type = type;
            this.text = text;
            this.description = description;
        }

        public String toString(){
            return text;
        }

        public void setDescription(String description){
            this.description = description;
        }

        public String getDescription(){
            return this.description;
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        listView = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);

        String[] headers = new String[] { "Section A", 
                "Section B",
                "Section C",
                "Section D", 
                "Section E", 
                "Section F", 
                "Section G", 
                "Section H" 
               };

        String[] values = new String[] { "Android List View", 
                "Adapter implementation",
                "Simple List View In Android",
                "Create List View Android", 
                "Android Example", 
                "List View Source Code", 
                "List View Array Adapter", 
                "Android Example List View" 
               };

        String[] numbers = new String[] { "One-", 
                "Two-",
                "Three-",
                "Four-", 
                "Five-", 
                "Six-", 
                "Seven-", 
                "Eight-" 
               };

        ArrayList<Item> itemList = new ArrayList<Item>();

        int sectionPosition=0,listPosition=0;
        for(int i=0;i<headers.length;i++){
            Item section = new Item(Item.SECTION,headers[i]);
            section.sectionPosition = sectionPosition;
            section.listPosition = listPosition++;
            itemList.add(section);

            for(int j=0;j<values.length;j++){
                Item item = new Item(Item.ITEM,numbers[j],values[j]);
                item.sectionPosition= sectionPosition;
                item.listPosition= listPosition++;
                itemList.add(item);
            }
        }

        setListAdapter(new SimpleAdapter(HeadersListActivity.this, itemList , listView));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        Item item = (Item) getListView().getAdapter().getItem(position);
        if (item != null) {
            if(item.type == Item.ITEM)
                Toast.makeText(this, "Item " + position + ": " + item.text+""+item.description, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Item " + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Item: " + v.getTag() , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

}
```